# Is it possible to save custom sized array of int arrays as field of RealmObject?

Tags: arrays, xamarin, realm

Basically I need datatype like this:

```
int[] list1 = new int[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] list2 = new int[4] { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int[] list3 = new int[4] { 1, 3, 2, 1 };
int[] list4 = new int[4] { 5, 4, 3, 2 };

int[][] lists = new int[][] {  list1 ,  list2 ,  list3 ,  list4  };
```

Custom sized array of arrays with 4 integer numbers.

So can I do it in Realm database?

Feels like it's better to replace "Custom sized array" by `List<int[4]>` but I doubt this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this, here is one. ;-)

I would create two `RealmObject`s. One that defines a single element of your array (a `Color` defined by four integers in my example) and a `RealmObject` that holds an `IList` of these array elements.

#### Example RealmObjects:

```
public class Color : RealmObject
{
    public int R { get; set; }
    public int G { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int A { get; set; }

    public int[] RGBA
    {
        get { return new int[] { R, G, B, A }; }
        set { R = value[0]; G = value[1]; B = value[2]; A = value[3]; }
    }
}

public class MaterialColors : RealmObject
{
    public string Material { get; set; }
    public Color PrimaryColor { get; set; }
    public IList<Color> AlternativeColors { get; }
    public void AddAlts(Color[] ca)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ca.Length; i++)
        {
            AlternativeColors.Add(ca[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Usage Example:

```
using (var realm = Realm.GetInstance(new RealmConfiguration { SchemaVersion = 1 }))
{
    var primary = new Color { RGBA = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 } };
    var alt1 = new Color { RGBA = new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 } };
    var alt2 = new Color { RGBA = new int[] { 1, 3, 2, 1 } };
    var alt3 = new Color { RGBA = new int[] { 5, 4, 3, 2 } };

    var material = new MaterialColors
    {
        Material = "StackOverflow",
        PrimaryColor = primary,
    };
    // Add array element one at a time... 
    material.AlternativeColors.Add(alt3);
    // Add multiple elements (array[]) via custom method...
    material.AddAlts(new Color[] { alt1, alt2 });

    realm.Write(() =>
    {
        realm.Add(material);    
    });

    var materials = realm.All<MaterialColors>();
    foreach (var aMaterial in materials)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Pri: [{aMaterial.PrimaryColor.RGBA[0]}:{aMaterial.PrimaryColor.RGBA[1]}:{aMaterial.PrimaryColor.RGBA[2]}:{aMaterial.PrimaryColor.RGBA[3]}]");
        foreach (var color in aMaterial.AlternativeColors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Alt: [{color.RGBA[0]}:{color.RGBA[1]}:{color.RGBA[2]}:{color.RGBA[3]}]");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
Pri: [1:2:3:4]
Alt: [5:4:3:2]
Alt: [5:6:7:8]
Alt: [1:3:2:1]
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Great answer from @SushiHangover.

We will have more direct support for this at some point. We don't promise release dates but you can [track the issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1194) to see when it is being worked on and source will be available.

If you have further design feedback on scenarios or desired behaviour, please add comments to [that issue 1194](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1194).